# retrive data from session and save to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to create a simple shopping cart, but i can't save the data from cart session.

Example:

```
product_code |  qty
Orange       |  10
Apple        |   5
```

I want to get orange quantity but it always get the latest one qty(apple)

Here is the value of `$_SESSION['products']`:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [product_qty] => 2
            [kode_produk] => 10
            [nama_produk] => Rainbow Cake
            [harga] => 75000
            [gambar] => rainbow.jpg
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [product_qty] => 3
            [kode_produk] => 15
            [nama_produk] => Black Forest
            [harga] => 100000
            [gambar] => black.jpg
        )

)
```

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION["products"])>0){

  foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //Print each item, quantity and price.
    $product_name = $product["nama_produk"];
    $product_qty = $product["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $product["harga"];
    $product_code = $product["kode_produk"];
    $_SESSION['kode_produk'] = $product_code;
    $jumlah = $_SESSION['product_qty'];
    $foto=$product["gambar"];
    $asu= $_SESSION["sssdasd"];

    $sql1   = ' insert into detail_pemesanan
     (kode_produk,jumlah)
     values
     ("'.$product_code.'","'.$product_qty.'");


     ';
    $query  = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli_conn,$sql1);
  }

}
```

but it always ended like this

```
Orang    10
Apple    10
```

Comment: To troubleshoot, what is the value of `$_SESSION["products"]`? You can output the value like this: `echo"<pre>".print_r($_SESSION["products"],true)."</pre>";`.

Comment: Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [product_qty] => 2
            [kode_produk] => 10
            [nama_produk] => Rainbow Cake
            [harga] => 75000
            [gambar] => rainbow.jpg
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [product_qty] => 3
            [kode_produk] => 15
            [nama_produk] => Black Forest
            [harga] => 100000
            [gambar] => black.jpg
        )

)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Additionally you really don't want to use `mysqli_multi_query`, it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: its okay man, its for my last exam, no need pro :(

Comment: What is the value of `$sql1` for each iteration? i.e. add `echo $sql1;` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: insert into detail_pemesanan (kode_produk,jumlah) values ("10","2"); insert into detail_pemesanan (kode_produk,jumlah) values ("15","3");

Comment: hollyy its works !

Comment: yeah, i re-empty the cart, :D , idk man feel so stupid, i wrong choose this class, im not programmer but i pick programmer class :(